# Call a function of the COM server .exe using C# or JAVA

Tags: java, c#, reference, com, activex

I have an .exe COM server which is really old and it hasn't been made in .net.
I would like to know if it is possible to access the functions of the .exe using C# or Java. I have tried to reference the server in the project but I got is this error:

> A reference to ... could not be added. Could not register the ActiveX Type library ... This is not a .NET assembly.

I am not smart about this, what do you think, in which direction I should go?
Usually I always add a reference to a .dll but I think it is not possible to add a reference to .exe file.

Thanks

Comment: Its quite likely possible, and there are libraries that can help you do this -- what have you searched for, and what have you tried?

Comment: Hello,
I have tried to run the .exe from the cmd, I figured if I can do that I can do it also from the project. But this wasn't successful or I did something wrong.
The other attempt was to place the .exe in the project folder and  make the instance of the the .exe object file in the project by 

<pre> 
object CheckCom=Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("CheckCom.Command"));
<code>

To do this I have to reference the object somehow otherwise I have build errors and I cannot use the object functions (CheckCom.function)

Which librarys help me do this?

Comment: I have also tried to run process mananger to check if the .exe has public functions and it looks like the functions exists.
So now the question is how to add it reference in VS C# or in JAVA?

Comment: Also what comes to my mind. After the .exe is running, to use a project to execute specific public function over that process using the managed C# app or JAVA app?
If so, how should I do that?

Comment: I have checked, the .exe has  been written in Visual Basic 6.0. Is there a way, to use pinvoke over VB6.0 .exe?

Answer (score 0):

After google-ing and reading some documentation, I have figured out how to add native COM exe as a reference, it can be dan after converting it to the CLR assembly. 
This .exe was not written in .net and therefore it cannot be added as a reference. To convert it to the managed assembly I used the Tlbimp.exe in Visual studio command prompt.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer